# Can I make a grid system with Material2?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular5 with Material2 and I would like to know if there is responsive grid system like Boostrap with rows and columns ? I have made some research and I found the [MatGridListModule](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview). The documentation is a bit short and does not talk about rows. There is nothing about offset or responsive class like `col-md` or `col-xs`. I am wondering if MatGridListModule is able to do the job I need.

I have also found [flex layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) but I do not know if it is the "right way" to build my grid.

Thank you guys for reading this post and have a nice day.

Comment: Did you check the example they have in Material? https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples .. Personally I would use flex layout, or even bootstrap itself. Material is not really meant for layout purposes but rather for OOTB components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<mat-grid-list>` is not a layout component. It's meant to represent the [Grid List](https://material.io/guidelines/components/grid-lists.html) component as it exists in the Material design language.

Flex-layout is the module most often recommended with the Material library to use for layout structuring, as most of the components use flex styling. It's possible to achieve a Bootstrap-like grid with the `fxFlex` directives, but it requires some thought and setup.

`@angular/material` itself is a component library, not a layout tool. It's compatible with any layout libraries, like flex-layout and Bootstrap. If you want the Bootstrap grid, go ahead and throw it in.